# CSS blend-mode really GPU consuming

Tags: html, css, performance, animation

I'm working on a website that uses layers with the "overlay" blend mode. These layers are moving to create a gradient effect on the background. I'm using CSS animations to get GPU rendering for these, but it's quite heavy and I can hear the fan from my computer every time the website is open and rendered.

I don't know how I could improve performances to reduce this overheating problem. Can you possibly help me ?

Here is the concerned part of the website :

HTML

```
<div class="backgroundTransparent">
    <img id="img1" class="transparent_background" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='calques_de_fond_1.png') }}">
    <img id="img2" class="transparent_background" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='calques_de_fond_2.png') }}">
    <img id="img3" class="transparent_background" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='calques_de_fond_3.png') }}">
    <img id="img4" class="transparent_background" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='calques_de_fond_4.png') }}">
    <img id="img5" class="transparent_background" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='calques_de_fond_5.png') }}">
    <img id="img6" class="transparent_background" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='calques_de_fond_6.png') }}">
</div>
```

CSS

```
@keyframes move {
    from {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

    to {
        transform: translateX(20%);
    }
}
.transparent_background {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateZ(0);
    mix-blend-mode: overlay;

    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-name: move;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

Here is a link to the site as it is at the moment, if it can help : http://brunobosse.wiboyd.fr:8080

It might also be important to note that without the overlay blend mode, the performances are much better. Is it possible to improve the overlay blending mode ?

Comment: How large are the images you're transforming? Try swapping the PNG images out for SVG images?

Comment: The images are about 100KB, I'll try with SVG and smaller ones

Comment: Slightly off topic, but I would not call it an overheating problem if nothing bad happens, really. Fans spinning during intensive stuff is normal behavior.  Is there any actual visible performance loss in your animation?

Comment: You're right about the fact that it's not a real hardware issue. Will edit. 
Well the inspector from Chrome clearly shows that there is about 20FPS generated, and the limitation comes from the GPU

Comment: @ArnaudMiguet now the title is much better, helps people looking for this in the future a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up not applying overlay to the background as it is way too GPU intense, only to smaller elements in the DOM.